# Using PAM with nginx in CentOS 7

Tags: nginx, centos, rpm, pam, rhel7

I'm new to linux. I'm planning on using PAM with linux user to authenticate nginx server access. I installed nginx from epel. But it seems that auth_pam module is not available with the nginx rpm. Can anyone give me some insight?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile ngx_http_auth_pam_module from source in CentOS 7, packaged version available for Debian only (nginx-extras or nginx-full package).

See source repo for details: https://github.com/stogh/ngx_http_auth_pam_module

Comment: Thanks Aleksey. But the problem I need to also package it back to rpm. Unlike few others, nginx doesn't provide a spec file in the distribution for building rpm.

Comment: I think, compiling from source (if standard package missed some 3rd party modules) is optimal way to have latest nginx version at any time you need. Sorry, cant help you with rpm building from source.

Answer (score 0):

The pam nginx module *is* available via RPM installation [here](https://extras.getpagespeed.com/redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/nginx-module-auth-pam.html):

```
yum install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-el7-latest.rpm
yum install nginx-module-auth-pam
```

To enable this module, add the following to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and reload nginx:

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;
```

Comment: you want to be paid a subscription with PayPal because you've compiled an RPM, but there is a free version: https://github.com/jfut/nginx-module-auth-pam-rpm/releases

Comment: @maxadamo with this free version of yours how an end user is supposed to figure out which NGINX version it is for by looking at your [releases](https://github.com/jfut/nginx-module-auth-pam-rpm/releases)? You're lacking RPM repository to facilitate updates *in production* not to say there's not even `--with-compat` in your spec file. Don't get me started on this! :D

Comment: I can understand. I noticed that this version, works with the vanilla version, distributed with CentOS 7: nginx 1.16. RPM repository is not a problem for me (I have mine), but it lacks a version for nginx 1.18. ON THE OTHER SIDE: if this package is available for free on Ubuntu. I could install nginx on ubuntu if I need this module.